# Cartesian equation of a line

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I can understand that the following are not the equations of a line, because both the equations refers to the plane $\pi : x - y + z = 2$:

$
\begin{cases}
x - y + z = 2 \\
3x - 3y + 3z = 6
\end{cases}
$

But why the following cartesian equations does not represent a line?

$
\begin{cases}
x - y + z = 2 \\
3x - 3y + 3z = 1
\end{cases}
$

Comment: Do you have consistency for the second set of equations?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel No, I had not noticed it before. So, the two planes doesn't intersect, right?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Planes are parallel ... there is no intersection, there is no common line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are on $\Bbb R^3$, so a line is describe by two equations

$$
\begin{cases}
a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z=b_1\\
a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z=b_2
\end{cases}
$$

such that let $A$ the matrix of coefficients

$$
rk A=rk
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}
\end{pmatrix}=2.
$$

In your case the matrix $A$ has rank one.

Moreover if $rkA=1$ and $rkA|b=1$ then the planes coincide and if $rkA=1$, and $rkA|b=2$ then the planes are parallel.

Comment: So if $rkA = rkA|b = 2$ the planes intersects forming a line, right?

Comment: Sure, if $rkA=2$ then also $A|b$ has rank $2$, and in that case you have a line.